# Change value JS, PHP getting old value

Tags: php, javascript

I've a silly problem.

Depending on a the visibility of a div I want to set a hidden value

```
if($('#crewMember').is(':visible')) {
  $('#visibility').attr('value', 'hidden')
} else {
  $('#visibility').attr('value', 'visible')
}
```

This works. I've checked it via FireBug and I can see that the HTML has changed.

But when I try to get this value after form submission I get the original value, not the changed value.

```
echo $_POST['visibility']
//returns default value, not the adjusted valueHow come?
```

How come?

**EDIT**
SOme example code

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#div').click(function() {
      $('#visibility').val('hidden');
      $('#value').html('hidden value: ' + $('#visibility').val());
    });

    $('#value').html('hidden value: ' + $('#visibility').val());
  });

  <body>
        <form method="post">
            <div id="div">
                click this area to change value
            </div>

            <div id="value"> <!-- This div will show the actual value of the hidden field -->
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="visibility" name="visibility" value="initial value" />
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="button" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I submit this form the $_POST['visibility'] always contains the string 'initial value'.
Even when I changed the value with JS to 'hidden';

Comment: Could you show a full example of code that shows the problem, including the HTML?

Comment: check fieldname of id visability

Comment: How are you submitting the form ? ajax ?

Comment: I submit on the regular way, with a submit button. No ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ManseUK said, Change `$("").attr('value',...)` to `$("").val(...)` (see the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for .val)

But to answer the question as to *why*, you need to understand how DOM objects work in JavaScript.  For every element (div, p, a, img, form, input, *whatever*...) every single element is an object in the DOM.

Here's the important part: the *element* has a value, but also each *attribute* has a value.  In jQuery, when you use `.attr('value',...)`, what you are really doing is creating an *attribute* with the name of 'value'.  But this does NOT change the *element* value, which stays the same.

In firebug, it will read the JavaScript attributes and layer it on top of the element, which explains why it showed up that way in firebug.  However, when it comes time to submit the data to the server, the browser will NOT submit the attribute values - only the element's value (which has not changed).  But using `.val()` will change the *element* value, which is what will be submitted to the server.

Perhaps this will make more sense in raw JavaScript, instead of jQuery:

the equivalent of `.attr()` is: `element.setAttribute("value","...");`

the equivalent of `.val()` is: `element.value = "...";`

Do you see the difference? In `.attr()` you never changed the value, only the attribute.

Comment: The key is that the "value" attribute and the actual node "value" are not one in the same; one is merely initialised from the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `val()` instead (im assuming your `visibility` element is an input element):

```
if($('#crewMember').is(':visible')) {
  $('#visibility').val('hidden');
} else {
  $('#visibility').val('visible');
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit actually the OP had those mistakes, which I had corrected, and therefore the same mistakes are visible in other answers, as they had referred to OP's original code.